# Limit to data stored when using setPersistenceEnabled=true in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for a chat app. I have used

```
setPersistenceEnabled=true;
```

Is there a **limit to the amount of data that can be stored locally** & if the amount of data increases then are there some **performance issues** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The disk cache is configured to keep 10MB of JSON data.
2. `setPersistenceEnabled` is an operation for the Firebase Database, not Firebase Storage.

Comment: Are there any performance issues when the local cache size increases?
If not then why does firebase have a limit as 10MB